# Multiple jQuery Filtizr on one page

Tags: jquery, filter

I am new in jQuery. I m using jquery filterizr for a single page. I have two separate gallery . And I want to use filterizr on them separately.
I have given an id to the div of my gallery using below code,

```
$('#galleryID').filterizr();
```

But this code only work for one gallery. Second gallery has no effect. If I try to , filterize with second gallery id at the same time, it shows below error,

```
jquery.filterizr.js:814 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at n.fn.init._getArrayOfUniqueItems (jquery.filterizr.js:814)
at n.fn.init._handleFiltering (jquery.filterizr.js:707)
at n.fn.init.filter (jquery.filterizr.js:193)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.filterizr.js:520)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.js:3)
at Object.trigger (jquery-2.1.1.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.js:3)
at Function.each (jquery-2.1.1.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.1.js:2)
```

Thus, i am unable to use filterizr both of them at the same time. It only work for one div. Can anyone help me or give me some example to how i can use this jQuery.filterizr ?

EDIT: I have tried with different ID and also tried with class. But if i use class, then two gallery works as a single entity. Means, filtering does not work separately.

Comment: Try using a common class instead of `id` for both galleries

Answer (score 2):

Because you are selecting by `ID` which is unique and can't be used twice.

> `ID Selector ("#id")` Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid. [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

So you need to create a class and select it like so:

`$('.your-class').filterizr();`

**Edit:**

If you need to set multiple filterizrs, it's a bit tricky. First you need to pass an option to disable the default controls when instantiating your Filterizrs.

```
// container class, init first filter
var filer1 = $('.filer-1').filterizr({
    delay: 25,
    setupControls: false // this to disable the default control
});
```

Then, you need to select the nav control class:

```
// first filter nav
$('#filer-1 li').click(function() {
    // Set Active class
    $('.filters-filer-1 .filtr').removeClass('filtr-active');
    $(this).addClass('filtr-active');
    // Init nav filter
    var filter = $(this).data('fltr');
    filer1.filterizr('filter', filter);
});
```

**Here is an multiple filtizr Example:**

```js
// init first filter
var filer1 = $('.filer-1').filterizr({
 delay: 25,
 setupControls: false // this to disable the default control
});

// first filter nav
$('#filer-1 li').click(function() {
$('.filters-filer-1 .filtr').removeClass('filtr-active');
    $(this).addClass('filtr-active');
    var filter = $(this).data('fltr');
    filer1.filterizr('filter', filter);
});

// init second filter
var filer2 = $('.filer-2').filterizr({
 delay: 25,
 setupControls: false // this to disable the default control
});

// second filter section nav
$('#filer-2 li').click(function() {
 $('.filters-filer-2 .filtr').removeClass('filtr-active');
 $(this).addClass('filtr-active');
 var filter = $(this).data('fltr');
 filer2.filterizr('filter', filter);
});
```

```css
/* Basic css */
.layout-col {
 width: 50%;
 min-height: 100px;
 margin: 30px auto
}
.nav-gallery .filtr-button {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px
}

.nav-gallery {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0
}

.filtr-button {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.filtr-active {
 color: DarkRed;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.layout-pane {
 display: flex;
}

.layout-pane .filtr-item {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.filtr-item.orange {
 background: orange
}

.filtr-item.green {
 background: green
}

.filtr-item.purple {
 background: purple
}

.filtr-item.red {
 background: red
}

.filtr-item.blue {
 background: blue
}

.filtr-item.olive {
 background: olive
}

.layout-pane .item-number {
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/filterizr/1.3.4/jquery.filterizr.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout-col">
 <ul class="nav-gallery filters-filer-1" id="filer-1">
  <li class="filtr-button filtr filtr-active" data-fltr="all">All</li>
  <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="1">Green</li>
  <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="2">Orange</li>
  <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="3">Purple</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="layout-padding-wrapper">
  <div class="layout-pane filer-1">
   <div class="filtr-item orange" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">1</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item green" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">2</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item purple" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">3</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item green" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">4</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item orange" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">5</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item purple" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">6</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item orange" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">7</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item green" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">8</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item purple" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">9</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item purple" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">10</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item orange" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">11</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item green" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">12</div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="layout-col">
 <ul class="nav-gallery filters-filer-2" id="filer-2">
  <li class="filtr-button filtr filtr-active" data-fltr="all">All</li>
  <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="1">Blue</li>
  <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="2">Red</li>
  <li class="filtr-button filtr" data-fltr="3">Olive</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="layout-padding-wrapper">
  <div class="layout-pane filer-2">
   <div class="filtr-item red" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">1</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item blue" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">2</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item olive" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">3</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item blue" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">4</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item red" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">5</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item olive" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">6</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item red" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">7</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item blue" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">8</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item olive" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">9</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item olive" data-category="3"><div class="item-number">10</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item red" data-category="2, 4"><div class="item-number">11</div></div>
   <div class="filtr-item blue" data-category="1, 4"><div class="item-number">12</div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir.. I know about ID selector. But I have tried with Class . But when i use class, there is a large gap is created top of the both div. I cant not resolve the problem.

Comment: I've added a basic multiple filterizrs example but you still  need to modify the css to meet your needs.

Comment: Yes sir..it works for a single gallery .. but Does not work for two different gallery separately on same page.

Comment: Did you see the **Edit** section in the answer? The code snippet have 2 separate gallery working in the same page.

Comment: thanks sir. I am trying to run your code, but it showing

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
    at n.fn.init.t.fn.filterizr (jquery.filterizr.min.js:1)
    at main.js:2`

Can you plz help me in this regard? I have written your given js code in the main.js file

Comment: I've test it on jQuery v2.1.1 and it works, i guess you're trying to load a different version?

Comment: No sir. I am using the exact cdn that you have used in the ebove code.

Comment: That's weird! Are you sure that jQuery is loaded before filterizr? you can follow the code snippet above. it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I edited your code a bit and it worked for me.

Comment: it's not working when i call it dynamically,
with different dynamic id
$.each(postFilter,function (index,value) {
            var el = $(this);
            // var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
            var HrFilterizer = selector.filterizr({
                setupControls: false,
                gridItemsSelector: '.filtr-item',
                animationDuration: 0.2, // in seconds
                easing: 'ease-out',
                filter: 'all', // Initial filter
                layout: 'sameSize',
                },
            });
        });